# NativeScript reload Image

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

I have created a profile image picker in NativeScript with the help of these plugins:
https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-imagepicker
https://github.com/bthurlow/nativescript-imagecropper

This works perfectly fine.
I always store the Image in the same folder with the same name in order to overwrite the previous image.

I set the image path this way:
`<Image [src]="imageSrc" class="profile-picture" (tap)="pickProfilePicture()"></Image>`

But now, the new profile picture is only displayed when I reopen my application.

I have already tried `this.cd.detectChanges();` and resetting imageSrc with `this.imageSrc="/profile_pic/profile_pic.png"`.
When I change the name of the image when resetting it, it refreshes the View.

I assume that there is some caching going on or that Angular does not think there is a change as the `imageSrc` string stays the same. Nevertheless, I want the profile picture to have exactly that name.

Any suggestions how I can force a re-rendering of the Image?

Kind regards,
Force0234

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I encounter something like this on the web I add a queryparam to defeat caching. Perhaps that works in NativeScript as well:

```
this.imageSrc="/profile_pic/profile_pic.png?ts=" + new Date().getTime();
```

Comment: jep thanks that works, I have already tried that.    
But as I said, I want the profile picture to overwrite itself when it changes....